# Does wrapping a react native View with my own custom Component cause optimization issues?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, jsx

Instead of calling react native Views directly, I call a wrapper to create the view. I have thousands of Views across my app which call the code below, will this impact my app in terms of memory, performance? Just curious if anyone has details about the underlying nature of react native.

```
import {View as WrappedView} from 'react-native';
export const View = (props) => {
  return (
    <WrappedView {...props} style={[props.style]}>
      {props.children}
    </WrappedView>
  );
};
```